# LogitBoost R in package "caTools", which algo is it?

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting

What is the name, and where can i find documentation on the algorithm used in LogitBoost for the "one node decision trees"? 
R, package = caTools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for `LogitBoost`, we find

> The function was adapted from logitboost.R function written by Marcel Dettling. See references and "See Also" section. The code was modified in order to make it much faster for very large data sets. The speed-up was achieved by implementing a internal version of decision stump classifier instead of using calls to `rpart`. That way, some of the most time consuming operations were
>   precomputed once, instead of performing them at each iteration. Another difference is that training and testing phases of the classification process were split into separate functions.

So I follow the instructions and look at the "See Also" section, which has this note

> • logitboost function from logitboost library (not in CRAN or BioConductor but can be found at http://stat.ethz.ch/~dettling/boosting.html) is very similar but much slower on very large datasets. It also perform optional cross-validation.

So I follow that link and find [this article](ftp://stat.ethz.ch/Manuscripts/dettling/boosting.pdf): "Boosting for tumor classification with gene expression data" by Marcel Dettling and Peter Buhlmann and published in *Bioinformatics* in 2002. Of particular interest is the abstract, which describes the paper's contents in the following words

> Motivation: Microarray experiments generate large datasets with expression values for thousands of genes but not more than a few dozens of samples. Accurate supervised classification of tissue samples in such high-dimensional problems is difficult but often crucial for successful diagnosis and treatment. A promising way to meet this challenge is by using boosting in conjunction
>   with decision trees.
>
> Results: We demonstrate that the generic boosting algorithm needs some modification to become an accurate classifier in the context of gene expression data. In particular, we present a feature preselection method, a more
>   robust boosting procedure and a new approach for multicategorical
>   problems. This allows for slight to drastic increase in performance and yields competitive results on several publicly available datasets.
>
> Availability: Software for the modified boosting algorithms as well as for decision trees is available for free in R at http://stat.ethz.ch/∼dettling/boosting.html.

So this paper appears to be the origin of the algorithm used in the `LogitBoost` function.